# jQuery megamenu like

Tags: jquery

I have a navmenu UL, nothing special..Button1, Button2, Button 3....button 8

I want on mouseenter the div="div2" (that is hidden) to fadeIn and to fadeOut only if mouse is out (mouseout) from Button1 and Div2..

so what I did

```
$(document).ready(function() {
    $(".dropdown").hide();
    $("#menu li:nth-child(1)").addClass('menu_li1');
    $("#menu li:nth-child(2)").addClass('menu_li2');
    $("#menu li:nth-child(3)").addClass('menu_li3');
    $("#menu li:nth-child(4)").addClass('menu_li4');
    $("#menu li:nth-child(5)").addClass('menu_li5');
    $("#menu li:nth-child(6)").addClass('menu_li6');
    $("#menu li:nth-child(7)").addClass('menu_li7');
    $("#menu li:nth-child(8)").addClass('menu_li8');
    $('.menu_li1').mouseenter(function() {
        if ($('.dropdown').is(':visible')) { //.dropdown is div's class
        } else {
            $('.dropdown').fadeIn();
        }

    });
    jQuery('.dropdown').mouseout(function() {
        if ($('.dropdown').mouseleave()) {
            $('.dropdown').fadeOut();
        }
    });
});​
```

firebug gives no error, I just can't achieve the result that I need.

Comment: Could you provide the HTML too, or even better, make a jsfiddle.

Comment: http://womensos.gr/ check the firs_button effect

Answer (score 0):

I see that you have not written the **mouseout** event for the `menu_li1` in the first place.. So how would you expect it to **fadeout** when you go to some other li..